# Python: Numbers in list

Tags: python

I want a user to input number in program and to write ever number to the list like that:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6] # wanting result

list.append(int(input())) # code
```

But I get it:

```
[123456]
```

How do I beat the number on bunch of numbers?

Thank you)

Comment: How are you entering the data? Is it in a loop. If you enter `123456` how do you want to interpret that? If you are wanting each character to be taken down as a number, then just realize there can be no 2 digit numbers. Most people would new line separate there numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If the user inputs one string (so `123456`), you have to add the individual characters like this:

```
mylist = []
inp = input()
for c in inp:
    mylist.append(int(c))
```

Comment: `mylist = list(inp)` is much easier.

Comment: I know that's possible, but I was trying to keep the code as close to that of the OP as possible, without introducing functions that were not necessary. It could be done in a one-line, but that wouldn't necessarily make it easier to understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what the user is entering. If the user simply enters `>>> 123456`, you could use:

```
user_list = [int(x) for x in input()]
```

More generally, you're going to have to figure out what the expected user input is, and parse that.

Comment: It looks to me like the OP wants to add to a preexisting list as opposed to create a completely new one.

Comment: I was extrapolating from the stated desired output, single input statement, and the incorrect output (which didn't have any other elements in it). But I take your point; if the OP wants to append to a pre-existing list, my example would need to change a bit.